# Auto Scroll Gridview when an event is fired

Tags: gridview, scroll

I am creating a master entry where in i need to fill the cells of gridview.And i am successfully doing that.Now my problem is that i dont have paging in my gridview.And its a long gridview.When i first select any cell of that gridview a textbox is displayed.On which i enter some data and then i press my submit button which is outside of my gridview.as soon as i press that submit button the next cell color changes to red[I have done that programically] which indicates that the value which i will now enter in textbox will be filled in this cell.and thn i again press that submit button.and thn the next cell get colored.In all im moving from cell to cell just by button click.I also have scrollable div under which my gridview is placed..somehow i have managed to fix my gridview header.but a stage comes when 
the red colored cell seems invisible as i have to scroll manually. and as soon as i press my submit button it refreshes back to the top record.What i want here is something which can focus the scroll around a particular row or cell index..I have tried hard but nothing helped
[image]

Comment: No one is answering my question